# When fraud user votes are subtracted from my account, will the real votes I got over the cap count for rep?

Tags: support

I got around 100 rep today from fraud votes which will be deleted, causing me to hit my rep cap prematurely.  My question is, when the fraud votes are deleted, will the real votes count for rep?  Say I got 115 real rep, then 100 fraud rep, hitting my limit.  Then I get 100 rep over the limit, counting for nothing.  When the 100 fraud rep gets deleted, will the 100 real rep step in and count toward the rep cap instead of the fraud votes?

Say I have 315 from today, of which 215 are counted (due to the cap).  When the fraud rep is removed, will I end up with 215 or 115?  If it's 115, I'm suing somebody. (:P)

Comment: Just to be able to verify, to which account were you referring?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

When the fraud votes are removed this triggers a recalculation of your reputation so any votes that were after you (incorrectly) hit the cap will now count.

However, you should be aware that your reputation score will probably go down due to other posts being deleted.

Comment: @Popular, @ChrisF Whew!  A relief.  Thanks, guys!

Answer (score 4):

When "fraud rep" gets wiped out, it's like it never happened. It also causes a rep recalc. Recalcs start from your first day and tally votes in chronological order, so it'll be as if you'd just gotten all 215 rep in a row.